# problem with async a HTTP request in a loop?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, async-await

I have a problem with an http.post call.
I use a renderer which traverses a JSON tree and starts processes when they apply.
For one process I need to call a HTTP request with a variable.

but the response of the request comes too late.
In my browser console the return appears only after all other processes have been processed.

I'm thinking of an async await solution, but I can't get a result. What am I missing?

```
 public renderer(mappingField, jsonField, i) {
   if (condition1) {
    this.result = .....
   }

   if (condition2) {
    this.result = this.renderer(new_mappingField, new_jsonField)
   }

   if (condition3) {
    this.result = .....
   }
   
    // condition with http request
   if (condition4) {
      this.httpClient.post(url, proxyBody).subscribe(  res => {
          this.result =  this.renderer(new_mappingfield, res["_source"][new_mappingfield.epart], i)
          console.log('result thats too late' + this.result);
        });

   }
    console.log('undefined if http request comes too late' this.result);
   return this.result;

}
```

Comment: The issue is, that you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code in a very dangerous manner. What calls the `renderer` function and, would it be possible to refactor it to return some sort of a `Subject`?

Comment: @Fonty move the api call outside the renderer function, secondly, you can apply asyncronous code conditionally like this. `(condition4 ?: this.httpClient.post(url, proxyBody) : of(null) ).subscribe(<rest of your code!>)` The subscribe will execute but nothing will actually happen when condition4 is invalid

Comment: the api call outside the renderer function. must it be a async await function ? do you have a example for me?